# Phonegap Plugin htm2pdf: how to retrieve the generated pdf file?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, html2pdf

I need to create a pdf report out of my application (android) written in html5/js and compiled by phonegap. Came across the html2pdf plugin and referenced it in config.xml (at.modalog.cordova.plugin.html2pdf)
Using the example code ("report" is a string variable containing all the html):

```
   window.html2pdf.create(
        report,
        "test.pdf",
        success,
        error
    )
   function success(status) {
     alert(status)
   }
```

Doing this, the pdf is displayed on the screen and finish.
Could not find the test.pdf file on the device.
So the question is: how to manage that the pdf is not just occupying the whole screen but appears in a separate window or div and where is the actual generated pdf file ?

Any help is very much appreciated, because now I got stucked.
Thanks a lot !

Chris

Comment: I don't know anything about this but [according to docs](https://github.com/moderna/cordova-plugin-html2pdf), the second parameter is not just a file name but instead a full file path. So I would think you'd just need to use whatever API gets you the user's writable storage area.

Comment: I would also encourage you to [read this post by the creator of iText](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12384410/231316) (the underlying PDF library that you are using) about some considerations when using that very old version of the library.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I already tried to use "file:///sdcard/test.pdf" as filename, did not work either.